# Missing spaces in conditionals

Tags: spacing, macros, conditionals, strings

I'm trying to print two different text if a string contains a ',' or not. The conditional is working, but the text is getting printing without spaces.

This is the code for the command:

```
\NewDocumentCommand {\dayeach} { O{} m}
  {
      \IfInteger{#1}
      {
        \IfSubStr{#2}{,}
            {#1 /day each:}
            {#1 /day}
      }
      {#1}
      %end if%
      {#2}

  }
```

And this is an example of how i call it:

```
\dayeach[3]{drink, eat}
```

with that i'm getting:

"3/dayeach: drink, eat""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `expl3` syntax. After `\ExplSyntaxOn`allspacesareignoreduntilthe`\ExplSyntaxOff`. Inside `\ExplSyntaxOn` a space is produced with `~`, so you need to use some of these:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \dayeach { O{} m }
  {
    \IfInteger{#1}
      {
        \IfSubStr{#2}{,}
          {#1 /day~each:~}
          {#1 /day~}
      }
      {#1}
      {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\dayeach[3]{drink, eat}

\dayeach[3]{sleep}
\end{document}
```

However, since you're using `expl3` anyway, I'd suggest to use `expl3`'s functions instead of `xstring`'s:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \dayeach { O{} m }
  {
    \IfInteger{#1}
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF {#2} {,}
          {#1 /day~each:~}
          {#1 /day~}
      }
      {#1}
      {#2}
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \IfInteger { m m m }
  { \xhark_if_integer:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3} }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \xhark_if_integer:n #1 { p, T, F, TF }
  {
    \tl_if_empty:fTF
      { \int_to_roman:n { -0#1 } }
      { \prg_return_true: }
      { \prg_return_false: }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_empty:nTF { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\dayeach[3]{drink, eat}

\dayeach[3]{sleep}
\end{document}
```

Both examples produce:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I'm using overleaf, and aperently it doesn't like exp13 functions.

Comment: @Xhark Hm... Overleaf has a slightly outdated TeX distribution, and `expl3` changed a lot in the past few years, so some things might not work. However I just tested the code and it worked fine. The only thing is the syntax highlighting that thinks that `\xhark_if_integer:nTF` is an error. But you can safely ignore that :-)

Comment: Yet I'd prefer `\tl_if_empty:fTF { \int_to_roman:n { -0#1 } }`